# Is there a way to fetch Tabulator object by selector like jQuery does?

Tags: tabulator

We can create object and then refer to it via `table` variable. Like this:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", { ... } );
```

But is there a way to get `Tabulator` object by selector, like in jQuery:

```
$( '#example-table' )     // Tabulator("#example-table")
```

Which will not construct new Tabulator but just return existing object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery with tabulator 4.0 and above you just need to use the ***jQuery Wrapper***

```
$("#example-table").tabulator( ... )
```

A full guide to using this can be found [Here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/jquery)

Comment: [guide](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/overview-install) missed that I should include jQuery before tabulator: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`. Also guide does not cover how to get already instantiated tabulator object by selector.

Comment: if you are not using jquery in your project then you should NOT use the jQuery wrapper. Tabulator does no need jQuery to function, it is only included to help devs using old source code that is dependent on jQuery. i would strongly recommend not using jQuery for new projects

Comment: I did not found a way to get Tabulator object by selector without jQuery =(

Comment: You shouldn't really be trying to access functional elements like that, these days it is considered bad practice. it is really only a hang over from the days of jQuery that developers still work that way. you should only try and access DOM nodes directly if you are trying to manipulate them. in this case Tabulator is held in the table variable, you should structure your code so that the table variable is accessible where you need it. every time you use a selector to find a DOM element like that the entire DOM tree is traversed to find it which is an processor intensive and inefficient action.